# Free objects in the category of all R-modules without linearly independent generating set

Tags: modules, free-modules

We can define a free module $F$ over a commutative ring with identity $R$ as a free object (with universal property) in the category of unitary $R$-modules. This is equivalent to the existence of a linearly independent generating set for $F$, called a basis as well as $F$ is a coproduct of copies of $R$. It is well-known in the literature that these three definitions are not equivalent, for non-unitary $R$-modules (e.g. Algebra, Hungerford, section 4.2).
Can anyone give an idea or a reference for nontrivial counterexamples of these (especially, in the case that free objects need not have a linearly independent generating set for non-unitary modules with non-zero scalar multiplication)?
Thanks in advance.

An additional explanation for the basis: by a basis $X$ for $F$ we mean a linearly independent generating set, that is, every non-zero element of $F$ is an element of $X$ or can be uniquely expressed as a linear combination of elements of $X$ with coefficients in $R$ (since $F$ is not unital we cannot necessarily write $x=1.x$ as a linear combination but we may have $x=r.x,$ for some $r\in R$! So any $x\in X$ may be written as a combination of elements of $X$! Thus we should consider the additional assumption for elements of $X$ in $F.$ Of course it will make things complicated.

Comment: hi Mona. how is "basis" defined in the non-unital case?

Comment: A free object does always have a linearly independent generating set; it's the converse that fails.

Comment: @atticusstonestrom  Hi. Thanks for your attention. I add a note to the question about basis. One can consider the uniqueness of expressions of elements of $F$  as follows:  every element of $F$ is "**either**" an element of $X$ or can be uniquely expressed as a linear combination of elements of $X$ with coefficients in $R$ (to avoid the cases like $x=rx$).

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks for your comment and answer. I added a note about my impression of a "basis". I think in your comment it is assumed that for an element $x$ of a basis, the expressions like $x=rx$ are not allowed. Can we consider these presentations for elements of a basis in a "new definition for basis" and does your comment hold in this case?

Comment: So, you originally wrote "linearly independent generating set" as your definition of basis.  To me, "linearly independent" means that if $\sum r_i x_i=0$ for $r_i\in R$ and $x_i$ distinct elements of the basis then every $r_i$ must be $0$.  "Generating" means that the smallest submodule containing the basis is the whole module.

Comment: Your updated definition of "basis" is seriously problematic.  For one thing, it implies that $X=F$ is always a basis, since your uniqueness condition applies only to the elements of $X\setminus F$.

Comment: By the way, the notion of "linearly independent generating set" as I interpreted is also not very useful.  The problem is that the "linearly independent" condition is too weak, since it only applies to $R$-linear combinations and not every element of the module is necessarily an $R$-linear combination of the generators.  So for instance, if $R$ is unital, then $R$ has a linearly independent generating set $\{1\}$, but $U(R)$ also has a linearly independent generating set $\{(1,0)\}$ (so there can be non-isomorphic modules with linearly independent generating sets of the same size!).

Comment: @Eric You are right. My definition gives a trivial basis in some sense. But the question is about the existence of any non-trivial basis as above for free objects. My problem with the classic definition that you mentioned is the unique presentation for elements of a basis. How can we interpret an element of a basis as an $R-$linear combination? For example, can we have by classic definition $x=rx$ for an $x$ in a basis (which also implies that $r$ is a right identity)?  Or how to strengthen the notion of "linear independency" to other elements (for example element of a basis)?

Comment: Excuse me, I wrote these questions in the comments just to clarify the issue.

Comment: Sure, you can have $x=rx$ for $x$ in a linearly independent generating set.  This is exactly what happens in the case that $R$ is actually unital and your module is $R$, for instance.

Comment: As far as I know the only way to get a well-behaved notion of a "basis" for a non-unitary module is to just use the usual definition of a basis over $U(R)$.  Concretely, this would be saying that $X$ is a basis for $F$ iff every element of $F$ can be uniquely written as a sum of an $R$-linear combination of elements of $X$ and a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of elements of $X$.  (So for instance, this would forbid $x=rx$ since $0+1\cdot x$ and $r\cdot x+0$ would be two different ways to express $x$ as such a sum.)

Answer (score 4):

Literally any nonzero unital ring gives a counterexample: if $R$ is a nonzero unital ring, then $R$ is not a free object in the category of non-unitary $R$-modules (even though it is a direct sum of copies of $R$ and has a linearly independent generating set).  The reason is simple: if $f:R\to M$ is any module homomorphism, then the image of $f$ must be a unitary submodule of $M$, since $R$ is a unitary module.  So, $R$ cannot be free, since its free generators cannot be mapped to non-unitary elements of other modules.

In general, non-unitary modules become much easier to understand when you realize they are just the same thing as unitary modules over the unitalization $U(R)$ of $R$.  Here $U(R)$ is the ring obtained by freely adjoining a unit to $R$.  Concretely, $U(R)=\mathbb{Z}\oplus R$ with multiplication defined by $(a,r)\cdot(b,s)=(ab,as+br+rs)$ (the idea being that $(1,0)$ is the unit so $(a,r)$ is the formal sum $a\cdot 1+r$).  A non-unitary $R$-module can then be thought of as a unitary $U(R)$-module where you define $(a,r)\cdot m$ as $am+rm$.  So free objects in the category of non-unitary $R$-modules are just ordinary free $U(R)$-modules--that is, direct sums of copies of $U(R)$.